# What is the difference between store.dispach, useDispatch and dispatch from useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";
```

...

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
```

...

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const store = createStore(
```

...
I see all trigger the actions but useReducer dispatch don't update the redux state.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Correct, `useReducer` does **not** update a redux store. `useReducer` is a regular react hook, and allows a component to apply local state updates in a functional way, similar to the pattern used by Redux, a very common *global* app state management library. Think of `useReducer` as component state version of Redux, which is app state.

`useDispatch` is a hook provided by `react-redux` that consumes a redux context (containing the store/state), similar to the functionality that the `connect` Higher Order Component provides when wrapping a component. These both provide a `dispatch` function to dispatch actions to the redux store.

`store.dispatch` *is* the `dispatch` function.

**Note:** `react-redux` `connect` HOC uses `redux`'s `bindActionCreators` to wrap(bind) the dispatch function to your action creators defined in `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: Terminology-wise, `dispatch` isn't a "higher order function".  It's just a function that's returned by `createStore`.  It's conceptually equivalent to a method on a class.

Comment: @markerikson Yes, quite right, it's technically `bindActionCreators` from `redux` that is the decorator and returns a function with `dispatch` composing the action creators from `mapDispatchToProps`.

Comment: Is there any functional difference between importing the store dispatch function directly, and using it to dispatch redux actions, vs importing useDispatch, invoking to get the dispatch function, and then dispatching that way? I don't notice any in testing but I'm afraid I'm missing something.

Comment: @CalebJay No, not really. Keep in mind that importing a store and calling directly `store.dispatch` will dispatch to *that* specific store object whereas the `useDispatch`'s `dispatch` will be dispatching to the closest store `Provider` above it in the ReactTree. Most of the time (*likely almost 100%*) a React app instantiates and uses only one store, so they are in most cases functionally equivalent. It is more conventional to use the `useDispatch` hook in the UI code.